# Modern substitute for BF494 or 2n3707 transistors

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, radio

This question has been asked before, here:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/263366/199668

But since it's been almost 5 years since that post, does anyone know any substitutes for the mentioned transistors? I'm attempting to make this circuit:[image]

I can't find these transistors on Amazon, and I don't want to wait 2 weeks for one to arrive elsewhere. Also why are they so hard to find today?

Answer (score 1):

Try a BC548 or BC549.  BF494 look like quite old designs and probably out of favour because of new, possibly better and probably cheaper alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question! I will try that.